# Use a cell value to generate filename and extension with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code where i am entering a value in cell "D2" of an Excel worksheet
and I also have button that generates a file when clicked . I want the file name to be generated from the value of cell "D2" with an extension of ".txt".

Example : cellname.txt

I enter in D2 : PSN_FILE

Then the file should be generated as "PSN_FILE.txt"

Here is my current code:

```
Dim val As String
val = Range("D2").Value
Dim iCntr
Dim relativePath As String
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "val.txt" => here showing error
Open relativePath For Output As #1
For iCntr = 1 To LastRow
Print #1, Range("E" & iCntr)
Next iCntr
Close #1
```

The file is created as "val.txt" not "PSN_FILE.txt"

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Needs a path separator and no quoting of `val`

```
relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & val & ".txt"
```

Comment: You might also need to specify where `val`'s range is located. `val = ActiveSheet.Cells(2,4).Value`